Broken symmetry vs emergence of symmetry
In many condensed matter presentations going from a gas/liquid state to a solid (especially a crystal) is presented as breaking the complete translational and rotational symmetry of the gas/liquid to only discrete translational and rotational symmetries. But when you look at the accompanying pictures of the gas it looks more like it has NO symmetry. At least not unless you average over space or time in some unspecified way. I don’t disagree that the gas looks symmetric microscopically near each particle (so near there no other particles in that volume). But wouldn’t it be better to concede that what is happening in this case is the emergence of symmetry. Other situations really do have symmetry breaking (beading rolling from top of Mexican hat or compression to buckling transition). But pushing the analogy so far as to call a gas symmetric when the drawing of the gas molecules even shows that NO translation or rotation could possibly map the system on to itself, seems misleading or at least confusing. It doesn’t seem like the supposed “full symmetry” of the non-condensed state is ever really used in any of the following arguments in the texts I’ve seen.
The other thing sometimes brought up is that the condensed state doesn’t have the full symmetry of the single particle Hamiltonians. But then neither does the gas! It’s not like in the gas the particles are arranged spherically symmetrically around ANY of the particles. Again, at least not on the length scale where the Hamiltonian is at all significantly non-zero.
So would anything be lost from the exposition by describing what is actually shown in the usual pictures and calling it a case of symmetry emerging vs being broken?
Then you could say the high temp system has no symmetry and that symmetry goes from zero to the final discrete symmetry as you cross the transition point. Versus now you are basically saying that we go from a full (infinite) amount of symmetry down to some lesser symmetry.
And some texts even say that gas to solid to is going from unordered to ordered, which would make unordered equivalent to symmetric. But if something is unordered it can’t really be symmetric at the same time!

There is a misunderstanding about what is considered to have the full spherical symmetry in a gas.
Certainly, it cannot be an instantaneous configuration because it would not be able to distinguish between different phases.
When we say that a gas or a liquid has full rotational and translational symmetry, we mean that the average one-particle density, i.e.
$$
\rho({\bf r})= \left \langle  \sum_i \delta( {\bf r} - {\bf r}_i) \right \rangle,
$$
where $\langle \dots \rangle $ denotes a statistical (or time) average.
In the case of a fluid, $\rho({\bf r})= constant$, which has the full translational and rotational symmetry. In the case of a crystalline solid, it is a periodic function with the same periodicity of the Bravais lattice. Then it has a reduced symmetry.

I agree that the gas has full rotational and translational symmetry, IF you average somehow (over long times or large volumes). But that’s exactly to me the issue; for the crystal, time averaging has no effect (doesn’t change the symmetry) and for the crystal, spatial averaging over a lengths much greater than the lattice spacing also results in constant density and so macroscopically full translational symmetry. So to force this to be a case of “spontaneous symmetry breaking” you have to finesse the explanation to do averaging for the gas but not for the crystal.

(cont.)
Basically we’re treating the two states differently just claim this is something cool sounding when it isn’t. So why not just concede that this isn’t like real spontaneous symmetry breaking, but the emergence of symmetry from a non-symmetric state? What would be lost?

There is nothing like symmetry alone. Symmetry is always a property of something. The spatial symmetry of condensed phases are symmetries of the average one-particle density, where the average is intended as the time average (no spatial coarse-graining). The case of a crystalline solid introduces a delicate point if an ensemble average replaces the time average without constraining the center of mass position. In such a case, the one-particle density does not exhibit the broken symmetry, and other order parameters must be introduced. But, apart technicalities, the fluid phases have the full...

...rotational and translational symmetry, while the crystal phase has a lower symmetry of the average one-particle density.   Your idea would be correct if you stated, "at the liquid-solid transition, there is the emergence of a periodic one-particle density from a constant one. It is incorrect to look at the fluid phase as non-symmetric. The only non-symmetric objects are the individual (instantaneous) configurations, but they are irrelevant to the description of symmetry.

Except the density of the fluid phase is not constant, UNlLESS you average out the disorder. So WHY are the instantaneous configurations irrelevant? Yes they are irrelevant to the description of the symmetry of the fluid state IF you consider the averaged fluid state. But why is it important to consider the averaged fluid state when we don’t look at the averaged solid state? I just don’t see how it supports anything in the following arguments about phase transition. Why is it so important to finesse the discussion to look at the average fluid state just to be able to say a symmetry is broken?

@kangermu Averages are important because the symmetry one is speaking about is the symmetry of the macroscopic state. For solid phases, one also performs time averages. Without them, the instantaneous configurations of a solid would not display long-and short-range order.

I do see what you mean. But in the solid it doesn’t take much time averaging to have a lot of order, and at (very) low temp a crystal wave function has the ordering without any non-quantum averaging. Maybe that’s partly what I wasn’t getting out of the textbook point of mentioning symmetry being broken. Given that it is meant that in all phases it’s talking about macroscopic/averaged properties, we see the system go from no (zero) macroscopic/averaged order (i.e. fully symmetry) to a sharp transition to increasingly “sharp” reduced symmetry as temperature drops.

And the sharpness of the reduced symmetry increasing can be seen either by needing to do longer time averages to get the same variance in the density at each point or by seeing that the variance drops for the same length of time averaging, as the temp goes down. Overall, the disorder to order character versus the full symmetry to broken symmetry still seems the the more intuitive description because the textbooks tend to show an instantaneous snapshot of the fluid state and call it symmetric, when that picture isn’t (only  a time average of pictures would, but that’s not shown).

So I get what the physics is here but just think the textbook exposition could be make less “misleading”. Thanks for the super helpful discussion! :)

@kangermu Unfortunately, there are many textbooks around with misleading figures and sometimes unclear statements :-(

The liquid-gas transition is indeed the black sheep of the family, without any apparent associated symmetry breaking.  Two things we can say about it are: 1) the critical phenomenon near the triple point is very similar to other systems with symmetry breaking, and 2) you can cook up a symmetry breaking description within some crude toy models such as the lattice gas, though the mapping is admittedly contrived.  It is better to think about the canonical example of little arrows on a lattice if you want to understand the Landau paradigm of symmetry and phase transition.
I also want to add a comment about the meaning of a symmetry in Hamiltonian.  What it usually means is, when you do a symmetry transformation on a physical state, you get one of its identical siblings, but not itself.
One example would be an idealized game of snooker.  Swapping 2-ball and 3-ball in the beginning, and the game would play out exactly like there was no swapped.  Except 2 and 3 are always, well, swapped: the configuration is never the same.
An counterexample would be swapping the proton for a neutron in a hydrogen atom.  The subsequent fate of the system is very different after the swap.
Back to the case of statistical physics.  A micro configuration of your system likely breaks a whole bunch of symmetries.  By rotating, translating, etc., you only gets its siblings.  When all siblings are equally likely to occur, the equilibrium (macro) state is symmetric.

I may have confused things by asking about the gas/liquid to solid transition. What I mean by the / between gas and liquid is either the transition from gas to solid or the transition from liquid to solid. Not the gas to liquid transition. My issue is really with saying that either non-condensed phase supposedly has full translational and rotational symmetry when to me it seems like it just does not have any symmetry. i.e. no translation or rotation maps the system to itself.
